# Is this unitary matrix diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $D$ be a diagonalizable matrix in ${\rm{M}}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. By Shur Lemma and Gramm Schmidt process, D is similar to a unitary matrix $U$.

Is $U$  diagonal?

Comment: There are very few diagonal unitary matrices ...

Comment: In this case, since $D$ is diagonalizable, so it is similar to a diagonal matrix, say $U'$. Now, by Gramm Schmidt process, $U'$ is changed to a orthogonal matrix, $U$. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is little bit unclear, so I will provide two answers to two different questions.

**1. If an unitary matrix $U$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$, is $U$ also diagonal?**

The answer is no. Consider following counterexample:
Let $D = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $R$ be the rotation by $45^\circ$. Then, $R^T D R = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1\\ -1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is unitary but not diagonal.

**2. If $D=UR$ is diagonal, $U$ unitary, and $R$ upper triangular, is $R$ also diagonal?**

If $D$ is invertible, then it is true. Note that $U=RD^{-1}$ is again upper triangular. Now, $U^* = U^{-1}$ is lower triangular but also upper triangular. Thus, $U^*$ must be diagonal and so does $U$.

If $D$ is not invertible, the it is trivially wrong. Consider
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ & 0 \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ & 0 & 1 \\ & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ & 0 \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Thank you 251257. But the $D$ introduced is diagonalizable with real spectra, inparticular diagonal. We have $I^{-1}DI$ is diagonal that $I$ is identity matrix. Also, $I^{-1}DI=U$ is orthogonal because $U^{t}U=I$.

Comment: @ela you have asked if $D$ is similar to an unitary matrix $U$, then is $U$ also diagonal? If that wasn't your question, then you should alter your question.

Comment: Yes. I hveve ask: If $D$ is diagonalizable real matrix with real spectra and is similar to an orthogonal matrix $U$, obviously, then is $U$ diagonal?

Comment: @ela I gave you a counter example.

Comment: Ok. Can you edit my question?

Comment: @ela: I have expanded my answer. I hope it helps.